# Count words from textarea , error switch

Tags: php

I have a form with an input type number and a textarea, named valoare and textarea
I have 5 radiobuttons,each with name option and value 1,2,3,4,5
so lets say for first radio button I want to display the number of words from textarea.

This is the code:

```
if (!empty($_POST['textarea']) && !empty($_POST['valoare'])) 

    {
        $option = "option";
        switch($option)
        {
            case 1: 
                    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                      $count =str_word_count($_POST['textarea']);
                      echo $count;
                      break;
                }
        }   
    }
```

what's wrong with this ? I don't see any result.

Thanks

Comment: no error , simply doesn't display anything :) that switch is made correctly ? , yea sorry , i said error but i checked now and is no error , if i remove $option = option is an error with the switch, but obviosly

Comment: $option = "option"; thats just a string, and that's the parameter used in the switch (?)

Comment: but option should be the parameter to switch , but i dont know how to write it , cause it needs to be declare

Answer (score 2):

That code is correct, but as you have manually set `$option` to the value of `option`, it is not `1` so the code in the `case 1` statement does not run.

You should place the `break;` outside of the `if` statement though in case you add more options.

You can also add a default option at the end:

```
switch($option)
    {
        case 1: 
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                  $count =str_word_count($_POST['textarea']);
                  echo $count;
            }
            break;
        default:
            echo "Option is: " . $option;
    }
```

By the way, if I understand you correctly, you probably want:

```
$option = $_POST['valoare'];
```

instead of:

```
$option = "option";
```

Comment: no , valoare has nothing to do with this ,with case 1,2,3,4 i want to select the values of radiobuttons , i changed it like that but i didn't display anything , just Option is option , because i declared $option = "option". i don't know how to write the parameter of switch , because if i write option , it needs to be with "$" , if i write it $option ,  $option doesn't now exist ..

Answer (score 1):

```
$option = "option";
        switch($option)
        {
            case 1:
```

how can you switch option  if option is already  defined? if you define $option="option" $option will never be 1.

Comment: yes u are right! i just get this .. but which is the parameter then ? $option needs to be declared , it's undefined

Comment: if i remove $option = "option" , the error is : Notice: Undefined variable: option

Comment: i figured it out eventually ! 

    switch($_POST['option'])

Comment: no wonder you nick name is @brainless :)

Comment: thank you thank you, far to kind